# Is the area of the parallelogram the solution set of this Differential Equation? [Illustration](https://youtu.be/O85OWBJ2ayo?t=1338)

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, determinant, trace, matrix-exponential

I know that the determinant of matrix describes a change of volume of objects in space. The exp of a Matrix yields another matrix, therefore the determinant of it should also describe some change in volume in space. In 2D, as seen in the link, is the blue area the set of all possible solutions of a given ordinary differential equation?

[image]

If so, is this the reason why det(exp(M)) = exp(tr(A))?

Credit: Visuals by 3Blue1Brown [Illustration](https://youtu.be/O85OWBJ2ayo?t=1338)

Answer (score 1):

The blue area is *not* the solution set. The solution set in that video is $Ae^{Mt}$ with $A$ an initial value constant matrix. The blue area simply depicts where $e^{Mt}$ sends the unit square at different time points $t$.

About the formula:

I believe this is Jacobi’s formula. The reason for it is as follows:

The determinant is the product of eigenvalues, and the trace is the sum of eigenvalues. It turns out that the eigenvalues of $e^M$ are $e$ to the eigenvalues of $M$, and so the eigenvalues of $e^{Mt}$ are $e^{\lambda t}$ for each eigenvalue of $M$. Therefore:

$$\operatorname{det}e^{Mt}=e^{\lambda_1t}\cdot e^{\lambda_2t}\cdot e^{\lambda_3t}\cdots=e^{t(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\cdots)}=e^{\operatorname{tr}M\cdot t}$$

Comment: Thanks. But is the blue area the determinant? I am confused because the author paint the determinant in green and illustrated one of the vectors in green and as far as I knew the determinat outputs a scalar not a vector.

Comment: The blue area is the unit area when scaled by the transformation. The *area* of the blue rhombus-area is the determinant. The author drew coloured arrows because they enjoy visuals, but the determinant is definitely a scalar. @LucasPerasolo